# Shortcuts inactive after login

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz, lightdm

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity (dual screen and `nvidia-driver-435`), and shortcuts configured in my settings (`Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Launchers`) as:

- `F5` for "Launch terminal"
- `F6` for "Home folder"

After installing `compizconfig-settings-manager` and `compiz-plugins-extra` (only to activate the "Put window" plugin and no other changes), the shortcuts above no longer seem to work. Disabling the plugin and restarting doesn't seem to restore the old behavior unfortunately.

I found a curious way of "re-activating" them without rebooting or logging out, which might point to the underlying issue. In the CompizConfig Settings Manager, selecting any active plugin in the "Window Management" section and disabling/re-enabling it somehow causes the above shortcuts to work again. When doing so, I can see a rapid shift in the top bar and maximized windows (see example below). I suppose this has something to do with *refreshing* the window manager somehow.

[image]

Whatever this is, **is there a way to do this programmatically**?

I am pretty sure it is **not** `compiz --replace`, which has a much more drastic effect. And AFAICT the other options in `compiz --help` do not seem relevant (although not sure what the CCP plugin is). So it might be another compiz utility, or perhaps something to do with X11 directly. If you recognize the effect shown above, please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to programmatically disable and re-enable a compiz plugin:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# retrieve list of plugins
Key="/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins"
Value=$(dconf read "$Key")

# convert to array
IFS=', ' read -ra ValArr <<<"${Value:1:-1}"

# remove 'put' plugin
Todel="'put'"
for k in ${!ValArr[@]}; do 
    [[ "${ValArr[$k]}" == "$Todel" ]] && unset -v 'ValArr[$k]'
done

# reformat as a string value
NewValue=$(printf ', %s' "${ValArr[@]}")
NewValue="[${NewValue:2}]"

# disable, wait and re-enable the plugin
dconf write "$Key" "$NewValue"
sleep 3
dconf write "$Key" "$Value"
```

This is kind of a hack, and I would prefer to know what part of compiz is actually watching changes to the plugin list through `dconf`, and triggering a *refresh* of some sort. So I am not marking this answer as the solution yet.